# 50% Grey at 0.5 instead of 0.18?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, color-management

why is it that 50% grey is at 0.5 instead of 0.18 in the color selection panels?
That doesn't feel consistent with a linear workflow I am used from other apps.

thx

Comment: 18% grey is a film industry standard. You'll find it on so-called grey cards used for white balancing cameras (old school). Skin tone for the average white person is 18% grey, perhaps not the most politically-correct observation, but there it is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The color wheel has three options. By default RGB, HSV and Hex(adecimal). The first option, RGB, uses linear color, but the second and the third are color managed. By default they uses the sRGB color space in you display device.

This question has been noticed by many blender users. You can see further details in [this blender development task](https://developer.blender.org/T41287).

If you want to use linear color in all color wheel options, you need to modify the default set up for color management, and set **None** in the **Display Device** of you BLEND file.

[image]

Comment: That saved me to get real color values in Python scripting, Thanks a lot !